# Reading a file and passing parameters to other shell scripts line by line

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

So, I am trying to automatize the creation of a user using bash script. I have the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp/new/

cat autoid`date +%Y%m%d`.csv | grep "THING" | grep "4B"
while read -r line;
        do
                name=$(awk -F';' '{print $10}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
                surname=$(awk -F';' '{print $10}'|awk '{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}')
                userid=$(awk -F';' '{print $8}')
                bash new_user.sh $userid $name $surname
                sleep 1
                bash basic_access.sh C $userid
                sleep 1
        done
```

The thing is I'm a bit confused here. I'm testing the command using echo in the place of calling the other bash scripts and it isn't returning me anything but the output of the "cat autoid`date +%Y%m%d`.csv | grep "THING" | grep "4B"" line. Tried to pipeline the end of this line to while loop but it isn't working anyway.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `read -r line` supposed to read from? What are the various `awk` commands used to set `name` et al. supposed to read from?

Comment: @chepner i'm trying to read a csv file that have semicolon as separator. The code inside the variables (name, surname, userid) is working fine, the thing is, how can I send de output of "cat autoid`date +%Y%m%d`.csv | grep "THING" | grep "4B"" to those other commands, line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pipe the output to the `while` loop. The variable `line` should be piped separately to each `awk` process (to fix your immediate problem; keep reading for a better solution):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp/new/

cat autoid`date +%Y%m%d`.csv | grep "THING" | grep "4B" |
  while read -r line;
        do
                name=$(echo "$line" | awk -F';' '{print $10}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
                surname=$(echo "$line" | awk -F';' '{print $10}'|awk '{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}')
                userid=$(echo "$line" | awk -F';' '{print $8}')
                bash new_user.sh $userid $name $surname
                sleep 1
                bash basic_access.sh C $userid
                sleep 1
        done
```

However, repeatedly calling `awk` to get a single field is inefficient. Let `read` do the splitting. (Included are other miscellaneous fixes and improvements.)

```
grep "THING" "autoid$(date +%Y%m%d).csv" | grep "4B" | 
  while IFS=";" read -ra fields; do 
    read name surname <<< "${fields[9]}"
    userid=${fields[7]}
    bash new_user.sh "$userid" "$name" "$surname"
    sleep 1
    bash basic_access.sh C "$userid"
    sleep 1
 done
```

Comment: thank you! the second code worked perfectly. The first one did not, tho

Comment: I didn't try debugging the first code; there are probably other unidentified bugs that got fixed in the second version incidentally.